# How to get more error info from a selenium geckodriver failure?

Tags: java, firefox, marionette, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I'm using the headless `firefox 59.x` plugin on `geckodriver 0.19.1` with selenium `3.5.3`

Once in a while, one of my tests fails with seemingly being unable to create a geckodriver session. here is the error message:

```
connection refused
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: '5ed435662ab', ip: '192.1.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1043-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:           0x4edb3c - backtrace::backtrace::trace::hc4bd56a2f176de7e
   1:           0x4edb72 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he3b2a15d39027c46
   2:           0x440ac8 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::ha0fbd6d1a1131b43
   3:           0x447ba9 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::hf0532ddb9e159684
   4:           0x428570 - <webdriver::server::Dispatcher<T, U>>::run::h2119c674d7b88193
   5:           0x4029b9 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h21d98a9ff86d4c25
   6:           0x40be65 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h5cff0c9b18cfdbba
   7:           0x5e6a6c - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
                        at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:99
   8:           0x41eb22 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::h413eb1d9d9f1c473
   9:           0x5df13b - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>
                        at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:692
                         - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread
                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21
                         - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start
                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84
```

Is the only info useful here "connection refused"? How can I get more info?

Note there is an issue [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1413292) that has been created to stop showing the confusing rust stacktrace with the errors. Will that also show more error info?

Is there a way to configure geckodriver to get a log of these failures so i know the cause?

One time the cause was GTK3 being missing. but this time it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is it's in the geckodriver log. The information is hard to decipher but it is there.